# From which version of JHipster, Okta integration is possible?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

We are using JHipster 3.10.0, and its documentation doesn't have Okta under options/securing your app. If I still change authenticationType to oauth2, it gives errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been implemented in JHipster version 4.10.0, please see release notes https://www.jhipster.tech/2017/10/17/jhipster-release-4.10.0.html

However, it does not make much sense to regenerate for this feature, following Okta docs should be enough.

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project ingestor: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: method references are not supported in -source 1.7
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)

I am using java version 1.8. Still I see this error.

Comment: This comment  looks like it is not related to your question, please make some research as it looks like a basic java question and maybe open a new one with more details.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.